# How to compress a very large number into alphanumeric (in PHP)?

Tags: php

I want to compress a very large number into alphanumeric[0-9a-zA-Z].
Of'course, the easiest way is to use a in-build php function called 'base64_encode()', but I quite depreciate this method,  which making extra chars such as '/' and '='. Even more, base64_encode do nothing for compressing the number, because this function regard the number as a string.

I had thought about another in-bulid function called 'base_convert()', but it can just convert the number into a charset [0-9a-z], making the result more longer.

I am now using a cheap way to achieve my goal:

```
function compress_int($num) {
    $chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    $result = '';

    while( $num ) {
        $mod = $num % 52;
        $num = intval($num / 52);

        $result .= $chars[$mod];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

However, I think it very inefficiency. So I quite appreciate the one who can tell me a better way with higher efficiency. ^_^

Comment: Any comment on my answer?

Answer (score 14):

Here is one I have made before for a c++ application. Feel free to use it.

```
// $num - the number we want to convert
// $symbols - the chars you want to use e.g. '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
// &$out is a pointer to your $result
function intToBase($num, $symbols, &$out){
    
    // get the radix that we are working with
    $radix = strlen($symbols);
    
    $pos = strlen($out)-1;
    
    if($num==0){
        // if our number is zero then we can just use the first character of our symbols and we are done.
        $out[$pos] = $symbols[0];
    }else{
        // otherwise we have to loop through and rebase the integer one character at a time.
        while ($num > 0) {
            // split off one digit
           $r = $num % $radix;
            // convert it and add it to the char array
            $out[$pos] = $symbols[$r];
            // subtract what we have added to the compressed string
            $num = ($num - $r) / $radix;
            $pos--;
        }
    }
};
```

To use simply:

```
$num = 123004954712; //whatever number you want to compress
$result = "";// the result variable we will be writing to
$chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';// the caracters of our custom base.
intToBase($num, $chars, $result);// the call
// now our $result variable will have the rebased string.
```

Comment: Any reason why there is a down vote on this? I put some effort into translating this to php from c++. While I can see that it is a very similar answer to the question there are modifications that improve efficiency (string concatenation for example is expensive.)

Answer (score 9):

Just to complete Goran's answer and save someone's time, here's the function to get the int value back after you convert it:

```
function baseToInt($base, $symbols, &$out) {
    //get length of the char map, so you can change according to your needs
    $radix = strlen($symbols);

    //split the chars into an array and initialize variables
    $arr = str_split($base,1);
    $i = 0;
    $out = 0;

    //loop through each char assigning values
    //chars to the left are the least significant
    foreach($arr as $char) {
        $pos = strpos($symbols, $char);
        $partialSum = $pos * pow($radix, $i);
        $out += $partialSum;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

The call is exactly the same as Goran's:

```
$number = 123456;
$symbols = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

$strBase = "";
intToBase($number, $symbols, $strBase);

$intReturn = 0;
baseToInt($strBase, $symbols , $intReturn);

echo $strBase."<br>"; //e7w
echo $intReturn; //123456
```

Comment: This did not not work (for me) in PHP 7.4

I had to reverse the array in order to recreate the original number 

  ...

NEW:  $arr= array_reverse($arr);**
...

Answer (score 3):

Goran answer is completely valid, but over the years PHP became a little bit more strict and has changed slightly the use of reference, so to update it to today times we can use:

```php
function intToBase(int $num)
{
    $symbols = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    // get the radix that we are working with
    $radix = strlen($symbols);
    $out   = [];
    if ($num === 0) {
        // if our number is zero then we can just use the first character of our symbols and we are done.
        return $symbols[0];
    }
    // otherwise we have to loop through and rebase the integer one character at a time.
    while ($num > 0) {
        // split off one digit
        $r = $num % $radix;
        // convert it and add it to the char array
        array_unshift($out, $symbols[$r]);
        // subtract what we have added to the compressed string
        $num = (int)floor(($num - $r) / $radix);
    }


    return implode('', $out);
}
```

This version will work with strict types.

Comment: For performance: instead of using `array_unshift` you should `$out[] = $symbols[$r]` and then instead of `implode('', $out)` you should `implode('', array_reverse($out))`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above algorithms, I've fixed it to work with VERY long numbers as well ,  using GMP .
Its a bit more effecient code , and sharing both encode/decode ways:

```
function intToBase(int|string $num)
{
    // sometimes $num is sent using gmt_intval which of type string on very very large numbers                                                                     
    if ( ! is_numeric($num) ) return 0;
    $symbols = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    // get the radix that we are working with
    $radix = strlen($symbols);
    $out   = [];
    if ($num === 0) { 
        // if our number is zero then we can just use the first character of our symbols and we are done.
        return $symbols[0];
    }    
    // otherwise we have to loop through and rebase the integer one character at a time.
    while ($num > 0) { 
        // split off one digit
        $r = (int) gmp_div_r ($num, $radix);  // $num % $radix
        // convert it and add it to the char array
        $out[] = $symbols[$r];
        // subtract what we have added to the compressed string
        $num = gmp_div ( gmp_sub($num, $r), $radix); // ($num-$r) / $radix
    }    
    return implode('', array_reverse($out));
}

function baseToInt($base) {
    $symbols = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    //get length of the char map, so you can change according to your needs
    $radix = strlen($symbols);

    //split the chars into an array and initialize variables
    $arr = str_split($base,1);
    $out = 0;

    //loop through each char assigning values
    //chars to the left are the least significant
    foreach($arr as $char) {
        $pos = strpos($symbols, $char);
        $out = gmp_add ( gmp_mul ($out,$radix), $pos);  //  ($out*radix) + $pos
    }                                                                                                                                                              
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Confirmed working but the GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) extension must be installed first. For example on Ubuntu, `sudo apt install php8.2-gmp`.